# How I can simulate "tail" command for file on the Android file system?

Tags: android, adb

I have file on SD-CARD and my app using it as log file.
Is it possible through the adb to watch file with all changes in real time?
Like with `tail -f /sdcard/myfile.log` command.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to work great for me:

```
adb shell "while true; do cat; sleep 1; done < /sdcard/myfile.log"
```

Comment: Excellent! For windows users : substitute the filename with '%1' and place it in a batch file (for example 'adbtail.bat') in %WINDIR%:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell "while true; do cat; sleep 1; done < '%1'"`

Answer (score 2):

You can install [busybox](https://code.google.com/p/yangapp/downloads/detail?name=busybox-1.20.2r2) and then:

```
adb shell
tail -f /path/of/your/file
```

But remember that you should have root access to install busybox. If you are using the emulator check this one:
[How to get root access on Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with logcat.  You can add a view that will only show log entries from your app and it will be continuously updated.

Comment: Yes I know about possibilities of Android logger. But, I need log in specific own format. 
This is requirements of the my employer.
At the moment I do not see other opportunities to watch log besides rooting and busybox installation.

Comment: How do you hook up logcat to watch a file?  That sounds like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great app for this: [Terminal IDE](http://www.spartacusrex.com/terminalide.htm). It contains many linux commands, and it does not need root access. You can install it from [GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside). Is is free of charge (and open source, GPLv2).

One of its best features is that it can be used through `telnet`. Start it on your phone, and type `telnetd` command. It will start a telnet daemon, which listens on port 8080 by default.
After that you can connect it from your PC, with the following command: (use cygwin on windows)

```
telnet 192.168.1.8 8080
```

You should use your phone's IP address instead of the above one. After a successful connection you will have an arbitrary sized terminal on your PC, which is capable to run `tail -f` command on your phone. And many others, such as `bash` and all of its builtin commands.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Jesse's answer, to do similar with a file within an app's private storage area:

`adb shell "while true; do run-as com.yourdomain.yourapp cat /data/data/com.yourdomain.yourapp/app_flutter/yourfile.txt; sleep 5; done" | egrep -o 'sometext.{0,50}'`

(This example is for a flutter app on Android, but is similar minus the app_flutter directory.)

`do run-as` changes the user under which the command is run to the application.  By default adb shell user shouldn't have access to any files under an application's private storage area.

`| egrep -o 'sometext.{0,50}'` the cat command sends the file contents to STDOUT.  `egrep` is taking the contents & searching for `-o` (only) `sometext` + 50 characters" using regex (hence `egrep` instead of `grep`).

#### Last Line Only

Replace `cat` with `tail -n 1`.

Add `--line-buffered` to `egrep`

`adb shell "while true; do run-as com.yourdomain.yourapp tail -n 1 /data/data/com.yourdomain.yourapp/app_flutter/yourfile.txt; sleep 5; done" | egrep --line-buffered -o 'sometext.{0,50}'`