# adb shell - simulate “tail” command?

Tags: android, tail

Is it possible to simulate "tail -f" on android?

I'd like to write all the new data in one file into another file, just like:

> "tail -f n 0 a.txt > b.txt"

Comment: You have to install `busybox` in prder to add more linux commands to your device.

Comment: Is there an option to do it without busyBox?

Comment: Not as far as I know. The commands set of android is pretty limited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with some shell hackery, no busybox needed. Try this:

```
adb shell "(cat > /dev/null; while true; do cat; sleep 1; done) < a.txt > b.txt"
```

Remove the initial `cat` to simulate a regular `tail -f`.

(related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44288388/893755)